# Automatic login on Headless, console-only computer

Tags: 11.04, command-line

I am working with a Gumstix computer running a console-only version of Ubuntu (courtesy of the Linaro project, which is quite fantastic), and when I boot the computer while connected to it over a serial console (ttyUSB) it automatically launches as root.  I think this is a terrible idea.  I'd rather it login as the user I've set up.  How can I set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you haven't created a basic user yet :P

Create a user for yourself... It'll ask you to enter a password.

```
sudo adduser <your_user_name>
```

If you cannot gain root privileges through sudo, edit /etc/sudoers

```
sudo vi /etc/sudoers
```

And uncomment the sudo group line to look like this:

> sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

Then add yourself to the sudo group

```
sudo useradd -G sudo <your_user_name>
```

If all goes correctly, Ubuntu should realise that there's more than one user and prompt for a login... I have a Pandaboard with Natty Headless on it, and as far as I remember, I've only needed to add a user